# How can I duplicate a mySQL table row but insert one custom value?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

With this code I am duplicating my table row:

```
 $old_name = "Laura";
 $new_name = "Sam";

 $pdo = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO animals (status, name) SELECT status, name FROM animals WHERE name = :name');
 $pdo->execute(array(
        ':name' => $old_name,
  ));
```

It is working well, but I need to put on the position of `name` by the new insert a custom value.

This is my approach:

```
 $old_name = "Laura";
 $new_name = "Sam";

 $pdo = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO animals (status, name) values(:name) SELECT status, name FROM animals WHERE name = :name');
 $pdo->execute(array(
        ':name' => $new_name,
        ':name' => $old_name,
  ));
```

The error message is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: Have you tried aliasing the table: `INSERT INTO animals (status, name) values(:new_name) SELECT a.status, a.name FROM animals AS a WHERE a.name = :old_name` - otherwise there's likely some ambiguity.

Comment: @CD001 Ok, I will test it and let you know

Comment: You'll also need to uniquely identify the placeholders (e.g. `:new_name`, `:old_name`) as the values are different.

Comment: Actually the query is still a little wonky, this might be better: `INSERT INTO animals(animals.status, animals.name) SELECT a.status, :new_name FROM animals AS a WHERE a.name = :old_name` ... you don't need `VALUES()` with `INSERT ... SELECT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `VALUES()` with `INSERT SELECT` and there's probably some ambiguity on the column names since you're both selecting from, and inserting to, the same table - so you should alias one of them.

Also, since you're entering different values on the `:name` placeholder, you're going to need two different placeholders.

This should probably do it:

```
$old_name = "Laura";
$new_name = "Sam";

$pdo = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO animals(animals.status, animals.name) SELECT a.status, :new_name FROM animals AS a WHERE a.name = :old_name');
$pdo->execute(array(
    ':old_name' => $old_name,
    ':new_name' => $new_name,
));
```